# What is the best way to use a custom fork of a python library in another python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-module

I am developing a python application. This application relies on an open source library that I have forked and heavily modified.

If it matters, the (very much WIP) forked library is available on [github](https://github.com/dominickj-tdi/couchdb-python) it it helps.

To import the forked library in my application, what I am currently doing is as follows:

```py
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', '..', '..', '..', 'couchdb')))
import couchdb
```

This works, but I'm not entirely happy with it for obvious reasons. It's far from elegant or flexible, and also seems to confuse my IDE. I feel like, especially in a language as elegant as Python, there ought to be a better way to simultaneously develop both an application and a library it depends on.

Both the library and the application are currently located side-by-side in a folder on my machine, sharing a virtual environment but residing in two separate git repositories. It is important to me that they remain in different git repositories, so nesting the library within the application is out, but the rest I'm happy to change.

I'm certain someone else has been in this situation before, so I'm hoping someone knows a way of doing this which is more "officially sanctioned" by Python.

Comment: `python -m pip install -e <github_path>`. This installs the library in your project but in a development environment. (-e means editable): https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

Comment: I actually did not know pip could install from locations other than PyPi, thanks. I'm going to have to look at that documentation some more.

Comment: In that case take a look here too: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3610. It explains how to pip install from github. Also if you want to install from a particular branch just append `@<branch_name>` to `<github_path>` so that it becomes `<github_path>@<branch_name>`. Without, the `@<branch_name>` it installs from master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your code is based on `couchdb` isn't really important, since it's not *compatible* with `couchdb` anymore, presumably. Just install it properly under its own unique name, then import it as you would any other module.

```
import couchdbdmj
```

Don't make your scripts depend on your development environment: configure your development environment to provide your custom modules in a uniform matter.

Comment: Thank you, between this and the comment by mattyx17, I think I know what I need to do now. I would assume I would want to move the development copy of the library out of the library's venv though, is that correct?

Comment: Correction: I mean move the library out of the *application's* venv.

Comment: Wouldn't the application's venv be exactly the *right* place for it? (Or do you mean moving the library's repository out, then installing the library itself into the venv?)

Comment: Yeah, move the repo out and install the library in the venv was what I had understood. Is that correct?

Comment: So, I did have to move the library out of the folder with the application's venv. Using the -e flag as mentioned in the comment above installed the library in venv/src. I have to keep a separate development copy since for whatever reason the git repo in venv/src wouldn't let me push to origin, but it does let me pull. So my problem is now solved. Just have to push from the development copy of the library then pull back to the copy in venv/src. Thank you!